# Как правильно делать респонсивность в Андроид студио?

Tags: java, android

Как правильно делать макеты для разных размеров экрана? Какой путь правильный, какие подходы есть? Я делаю так: создаю разметку xml на каждую величину hdpi xlarge и тд. Есть ли другие, более быстрые способы?

Comment: правильный подход - делать одну адаптивную разметку на все экраны (+ разметка на планшеты, если требуется). Новый макет создается тогда, когда требуется другое расположение виджетов на экране, а не разное разрешение

Answer (score 2):

Не ручаюсь за сказаные слова ниже:
один из способов сделать 3 - 4 макета с такими разрешениями

1. Самый минимальный размер экрана который вы хотите поддерживать
   (например это может быть 320х240 (240p))
2. Средний размер Экрана (например 800x480 (480p))
3. Большой hd (1280x768 (720p))
4. Огромный full_hd(1920x1080 (1080p))

Далее логика простая, подбираем макет по наименьшему разрешению (тесть если экран 1024x800 то выбираем макет 800х480)

профит

или написать программу, в которой вы будете создавать один макет, а она будет сама его оптимизировать под любое расширение экрана, хэхэ